# Making a column with links in each row of my DataTable active, shortening the column as well?

Tags: jquery, html, datatable, datatables

One column in my DataTable is called Logeion Link. It displays a url for each record, but this url by default isn't active. Is there an easy way to fix this?

The other issue is that.... With the full url displaying, the column is extremely long. I wouldn't mind changing the column's text to just say "url" with a that string being a hyperlink to the logeion url, which would probably do some shortening. How do I begin to do that?

I assume that I can hit two birds with one stone if I find out a way edit the html for a DataTables row and a particular DataTables column, then I could find a way to say "for this particular column (Logeion Link) of each row, make its html have a `<a>` tag and change the text for said `<a>` tag."

It's just... right now I'm unsure what selector or callback would allow me to change each row's html.

edit: The code for initializing my DataTables object is here

```
        words_table = $("#words_generated").DataTable({
    "data" : word_data_filtered,
    "columns" : columns,     //should this be global_ocolumns
    "aLengthMenu": [[25, 50, 100, 200, -1],
            [25, 50, 100, 250, "All"]],
    "pageLength": 100,
});
```

where columns is a list of columns objects

```
                columns.push({
                "name" : $(this).data("fieldname"),
                "data" : "fields."+$(this).data("fieldname"),
                "visible" : $(this).data("visible")
        });
```

I tried to deeect specifically when the name of the column is "logeion_url" (and yes, this works with the .data("fieldname") attributes) but this led to syntax errors.

```
                if ($(this).data("fieldname") == "logeion_url") {
           columns.push({
              "name": $(this).data("fieldname"),
              "data" : "fields.logeion_url",
                 "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
        $(nTd).html("<a href="+sData.fields.logeion_url+">"url"</a>");
                  }
              ,
              "visible" : $(this).data("visible")
         });
```

I was trying to go off of this forum's suggestion
https://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/25111/hyperlink-in-td

Comment: use render.  there is an example rendering a link here https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render

Comment: you're right! I'm going to copy and paste my code.

Answer (score 0):

so yes, the answer is to use render. I am going to post my code though a fair amount of it relies on background knowledge of my javascript file as a whole. But I'm at least going to talk about what was tripping me up syntactically in case anyone else gets confused.

I made a conditional to identify when the url column was being initialized. Then I had it initliazed like all other columns, except I included the render : portion.

```
                if ($(this).data("fieldname") == "logeion_url") {
           console.log("CREATING LOGEION URL COLUMN");
           columns.push({
              "name": $(this).data("fieldname"),
              "data" : fields.logeion_url,
              "render" : function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
                 return '<a href="'+fields.logeion_url+'">Link</a>';
               },
              "visible" : $(this).data("visible")
          });
        }
```

- I'm still not fully sure what "data" means since I was expecting data to be set to the same value as fields.logeion_url so originally, the return statement read `'<a href="'+data+'">Link</a>'`
  This led to an undefined url being made. fields.logeion_url *definitely* contains the url for each record, which is why this worked.